# How much ohm resistance I should put between tp120 base and uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have set up solenoid on of based on soil moisture, 
The solenoid is powered by 24 volts, so I power solenoid by 24 volt and Arduino uno by stepping down to 6 volt powering through Vin and gnd.

I have used resistance of 10k ohm but I have twice burnt em.
Not sure how should calculate resistance required of signal coming out from D6 pin to TP120 base !

[image]

Comment: Is the 24 V a DC or an AC voltage?  Can you draw a circuit diagram to clarify the connections?  [Click the Circuit icon on the edit-box toolbar, if you don't have a schematics program to use] Note, edit the question in reply

Comment: 24 volt dc, I have added Fritzing

Comment: Your diagram shows nothing connected to one end of the diode - is that an omission? What have you burnt twice? The resistor?

Comment: sorry fixed the fritzing, yea I am talking about resistor.

Comment: 1-2.2k comes up in a web search

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the circuit is connected as shown? I can imagine it not working if you've got the wrong value resistor, but I can't see any way you'd burn the resistor up and not kill the Ardino as well. Have you perhaps got a short from one pin of the resistor to somewhere it shouldn't be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate you need to know the maximum current the solenoid uses. The TP120 has a gain of around 500-1000. So the current going into the base needs to be 1/500th of the current going through the solenoid.

So now you know the current needed. Then you can calculate the resistance value you need with `R = V/I`. So `R = 5 / ( <solenoidcurrent> / 500 )`.

So with e.g. a 2A solenoid, you get a value of 1.2kOhm.